# Get Advanced Validation constraints for TextItem in Google Forms?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Is there a way to get the constraints (e.g. number, email or regexp pattern) for a TextItem in Google Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Issue 4216](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4216) is currently the feature request to expose the **Advanced Validation in FormApp**. Star that to vote for it. If you have a specific use case that would help the request you can provide that as well, but please don't post nonconstructive comments there like "*+1*", "*me too*" or "*when will this be done?*".